# How to set dependency in VBA in excel using if-then-else?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to excel and i'm trying to create a macro to automate my process.

So what i'm trying to do with my macro is to highlight each entry in column C depending upon the entry in column A i.e. if there's a name in column A and there's no phone number corresponding to that name in Cell C, then it should be highlighted,but what my macro is doing is that it is highlighting all the blank rows in column C irrespective of an entry in column A. So if you could suggest me a formula or an if-then-else condition based on this, it'll be a great help thanks....here's my code snippet:

```
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Columns("C:C").Select
'Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
   ' "=LEN(TRIM(C1))=0"
If (Len(A4 <> 0) And Len(C4 = 0)) Then
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
 .color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0

End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("D10").Select
End If
```

What i did in my IF condition was that i was trying to implement it for 1 row first, but it wasn't working either(I need to implement this condition on all the entries being made in column C depending upon the name enterd in column A)..and yeah there's a formula above that is doing the highlighting of the entire column but I commented it and was experimenting with if-then-else..so if you can provide me with an alternate formula for this thing, it'll be fine too

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting manually (i.e. without code)?

Comment: i tried doing that too via "use a formula" option under conditional formatting but it wasn't working either

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without VBA by writing a formula in conditional formatting tab.Select first cell in the column you want to highlight (in your case  column C), then go to `Home->Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.`

At the bottom you will see the box where you enter your formula. In your case it should be something like this:

```
=and($A1<>0,$C1="")
```

Dont forget the "equal" sign in front of the formula. Make sure that the row numbers match the row number of the cell you've selected. Press OK

Then go to `Home->Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules` and you should see the rule you've just created. In the "Applies to column select all the cells you want that rule to apply to and then click Apply and OK. You should be set.